# Can I install Windows XP, 7, 8, 8.1 in without IDE mode?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bios

Good day guys, I just installed ubuntu and it replaced my current OS Windows 7 Ultimate. Now I want to go back to windows and try to install XP but now I'm unable to install ANY VERSION OF WINDOWS because others says that it requires IDE as controller. Unfortunately, I can't change it in BIOS at startup.Please help guys :(
If I cant't change the controller in BIOS Settings is there any way to install it without IDE enabled?

Error message:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD

  Status: 0xc000000e

  Info: An error occurred while trying to read the boot configuration data.
```

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:

1. Insert you Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
3. Click "Repair your computer."

If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.

File: \Boot\BCD Status: 0xc000000e Info: An error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data.

Comment: What is the exact error you receive?

Comment: Why are you unable to change it in BIOS at start-up?

Comment: @Ramhound When I try to install Windows 7,8,8.1 I got boot\bcd error something like that, while in Windows XP I got Blue Screen of Death and stop error "A problem has been detected and Windows has been shutdown to prevent damage to your computer" With stop 4 or 5 stop codes.

Comment: @Dracs I don't know how to change it in BIOS  because when I press F2 at startup then choose advance, then drive configuration I see ATA/IDE configuration and I have wto options which is NATIVE and LEGACY. But anything I choose on those to I still same error occurs.

Comment: I need the exact error to help

Comment: Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:
   1. Insert you Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
   2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
   3. Click "Repair your computer."
If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.
      File: \Boot\BCD
      Status: 0xc000000e
      Info: An error occured while attempting to read the boot configuration data.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed any settings in the BIOS before installing Linux, you need to exactly reverse those settings before installing Windows.

If this is a drive issue, then you should remove all partitions on drive 0 (first hard disk) and choose to install windows into the unpartitioned space. XP should install fine on either IDE, or SATA.

Without knowing the specific error, or error code, I can't help further.

Answer (score 0):

**Using XP any longer is a bad idea.**

If you don’t want to manipulate your Setup CD (to include AHCI drivers), you need to set your BIOS’ IDE configuration to “Legacy” (which means “basic IDE”).

The error message indicates the Windows 7 Boot Manager is still there. Remove *all* partitions from your hard disk, especially the 100 MB partition. Afterwards, reinstall XP.